# Field benchmarkRun must implement MethodRule

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I now want to add junit benchmark to my alreadyexisting junit testclasses.I use junit 4.10.I added junit benchmark 0.7.2. When I try running a testclass, it shows java.lang.Exception: Field benchmarkRun must implement MethodRule. How to fix this? I thought junit 4.10 would have MethodRule as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working fine with JUnit4.11. I had to delete com.springsource.org.junit-4.7.0.jar from the classpath. So please make sure you do not have any old versions of Junit related jars in your class path.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply...I will check and confirm.

Comment: I donot have any old versions of junit. Stil it isnt showing any console output. I get the same error too. I do get the output when I do maven build, but not when I run junit test cases.